# Between 2 JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<script>
var array1 = ['2023-04-05','2023-04-06','2023-04-07','2023-04-08'];    //array1
var array2 = ['2023-04-06','2023-04-07'];    //array2
found1 = array1.find((val, index) => {    //find the date in array1
    return array2.includes(val);
});
$('.show').html(found1);
</script>
```

result 2023-04-062023-04-07
how to result like this 2023-04-06, 2023-04-07

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just filter, to keep values that are in both arrays

```js
const array1 = ['2023-04-05','2023-04-06','2023-04-07','2023-04-08']; //array1
const array2 = ['2023-04-06','2023-04-07']; //array2
const found1 = array1.filter((val) => array2.includes(val)); //find the date in array1
console.log(found1);
// display however you want
document.body.innerText = found1.join(", ");
```

If you find yourself with super long arrays, you can benefit from [`Set`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which offer constant time lookup for if a value is contained. For small arrays, it really doesn't matter and you might even find the creation of the `Set` making the `Set` approach slower.

```js
const array1 = ['2023-04-05','2023-04-06','2023-04-07','2023-04-08']; //array1
const array2 = new Set(['2023-04-06','2023-04-07']); //array2
const found1 = array1.filter((val) => array2.has(val)); //find the date in array1
console.log(found1);
// display however you want
document.body.innerText = found1.join(", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive your results by using this

```js
var array1 = ['2023-04-05','2023-04-06','2023-04-07','2023-04-08'];    //array1
var array2 = ['2023-04-06','2023-04-07'];    //array2
const found = []
array1.forEach(date => {
  if (array2.includes(date)) {
    found.push(date)
  }
})
console.log(found) // ['2023-04-06', '2023-04-07']
```

if you want a string instead, you can join the array

```js
found.join() // '2023-04-06,2023-04-07'
```

Comment: Then you can do ```found.join(", ")```